# Facebook - Impossible to define caption for the feed dialog

Tags: facebook, feed, caption

When I try to share a link using the feed dialog, I'm no longer able to define the caption.
As it's not possible anymore since July 17th to send caption as arguments in the FB:ui call, could you tell me how can I do it now.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuTEy.jpg)

I'm trying to find the right open graph tag to add but I can't find it anywhere.

Cédric